# Reshaping data vector into a matrix for deconvolution using a circulant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra, signal-analysis

Suppose we have a circulant matrix *S* made from pseudorandom binary sequence of length $N$ consisting of $0$'s or/and $1$'s. $1$ means that we can inject something for chemical analysis and $0$ means we do not inject into an analyzer.

The duration $D$ of this sequence is $N \times\Delta t$. A single chemical analysis, after one injection, will last at least $D$ seconds and this is how the sequence is designed. However, after running plenty of injections, we will have waited for a much longer time than $D$ so that each analysis is completed.

I have a question regarding the right approach of matrix multiplication to deconvolve the signal from the instrument according to the pseudo-random binary sequence. The detector has its own data sampling rate $f_s$. The circulant matrix $S$ will have dimensions of $L \times L$. However the raw data vector from the instrument will be extensively longer due to data sampling rate. Say, if our data sampling rate is $20 \texttt{Hz}$, and $\Delta t$ was $2$s, and $L=127$, then the number of points in the vector prepared for deconvolution would be $127\times 20\times 2$. This makes the data vector, $v$, $5080$ elements long.

The simple deconvolution equation would be $$\text {Recovered signal} = S^{-1} v$$

What is the logical way to make the matrix multiplication compatible, by reshaping either $S$ or $v$ with $V$ to allow deconvolution? Downsampling $v$ to $127$ data points will cause a significant loss of data, although it is done by some researchers in older papers.

Alternatively, some convert the vector $v$ into a 127 row matrix, $M$ so that multiplication becomes compatible, and place the remaining data in the columns of $M$.

What is the mathematical basis of doing so?

Comment: This question is related to mathematical application to chemistry research where Hadamard Transforms are employed to signal to noise ratio enhancement. I wrote a very detailed query before (now deleted) with the background but it hid the main question which I summarized here. Any pointer or reference would be helpful.

Comment: I believe you need a maximal determinant binary matrix of the same size as $v$. A tensor product of two circulant matrices from 2 PRBS in $\pm 1$ form (then translated back to binary) should reduce noise a lot. From wikipedia, Let A be an n × n matrix and let B be an m × m matrix. Then
 $\left| \mathbf{A} \otimes \mathbf{B} \right| = \left| \mathbf{A} \right| ^m \left| \mathbf{B} \right| ^n$. It's the inverse of the determinant (which is tiny) that reduces noise.

Comment: So the best noise reduction goes for any Hadamard matrix with the constant $1$ row and column deleted and mapping $1$ to $0$ and $-1$ to $1$. However I'm not sure if there's a reason for the circulant condition on $S$, if not just take such a 0-1 representation of a Hadamard matrix of the same size as $v$. To preserve this circulant property on $L$ inputs use the tensor product method I mentioned above.

Comment: The tensor product method deconvolves the time series for each sampler independently from the deconvolution of all $127$ samplers at one time.

Comment: Maarten Havinga, Your approach seems interesting, can you add a little bit more about the approach, starting with 127x127 circulant matrix $S$, and you have a $v$ which is 5080 elements. How do you suggest going about from there?

Comment: A 40 element maximal length sequence does not exist, better would be 63 or 31 timeframes. Define $(e(A))_{ij} = (-1)^{A_{ij}}$ and find a PRBS of the required length (amount of timeframes) with circulant matrix $T$. Then use $S'=e^{-1}(e(S) \otimes e(T))$ as new $S$. An easier formula for $S'$ might be $(S+T)_{(i,k)(j,l)} mod 2$ where the index space is now the cartesian product of index spaces of $S$ and $T$.

Comment: An easier formula for $S'$ might be $(S_{ij}+T_{kl})_{(i,k)(j,l)} \space (mod \space 2)$ where the index space is now the cartesian product of index spaces of $S$ and $T$ (so $i,j$ indicate the sampler while $k,l$ indicate the timeframe.

Comment: I think the key question still is how do go about circumventing the $S$ and the data vector $v$ size mismatch. The solution would still be acting on segment by segment. I would appreciate if you post it as an answer with little bit of more details because comments get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

By having a matrix with a circulant structure where all row pairs, at all relative shifts are nearly orthogonal, you can decorrelate:

PRBS (Pseudo Random Binary Sequence) almost certainly refers to a so-called [maximal length sequence][1] or $m-$sequence which is generated by a primitive recurrence of order $n$ giving maximal period $2^n-1.$ If you write the sequence in the $\pm 1$ formulation and border on the left and top by all 1 columns you obtain a Hadamard matrix.

How does this matrix help in decorrelation? The $m-$sequence is given by
$$
s_t=(-1)^{a_t},\quad 0\leq t\leq 2^n-2,
$$
where $a_n=\mathrm{tr}(\alpha^t)$ with $\mathrm{tr}:GF(2^n)\rightarrow GF(2)$ the trace mapping.
Since the trace map is balanced with equal number of zero and one outputs, but
$\{\alpha^t:0\leq t\leq2^n-2\}=GF(2^n)^\ast$ i.e., the nonzero elements of the field, we have
$$
\sum_{t=0}^{2^n-2} s_t = \sum_{t=0}^{2^n-2} (-1)^{a_t} =-1 \quad(1).
$$
Note that two different shifts $(s_t)$ and $(s_{t+\tau})$  [sum over indices modulo $2^n-1$ to get cyclic correlation] of the sequence also have correlation $-1,$ since the correlation is
$$
\sum_{t=0}^{2^n-2} s_t s_{t+\tau}=
\sum_{t=0}^{2^n-2} (-1)^{\mathrm{tr}(\alpha^t(1+\alpha^\tau))}=-1$$
and when $\tau \neq 0 \pmod{2^n-1},$ the above correlation is just a shift of the sum (1) and thus the same

This is the correlation of any two rows the unbordered circulant part of the matrix. I haven't checked the code but if this is the part they are using then the correlation  has magnitude 1 compared to the peak of $2^n-1.$

If they are using the full matrix [since they want a Hadamard transform] then the correlation of any two rows (other than the first) of the bordered matrix will be in general at most off by 4 from this value so in the interval
$$
\{-5,-3,-1,1,3\}
$$
while the correlation of the first row with any other row will be zero.
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_length_sequence

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this is not my main query. It is the same answer which you had mentioned earlier in the deleted post. The question is about not about *S* matrices or their constructions into a circulant. The question is related to reshaping the *raw* data into a matrix in such a way that its multiplication becomes compatible with matrix *S*. I wanted to know what was the mathematical logic behind that re-arranging the data in such a way? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks from me as well, I always search for "Hadamard" which due to your answer made me find this question. The question in turn gave me new mathematical ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

To circumvent the size difference between $S$ and $v$, one can use [JPL codes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPL_sequence). These are a XOR (which is modulo $2$ addition) of two or more maximal length sequences of coprime sizes.

After 2nd thought this is not the same as I advised in my comments. For two bit sequences of coprime sizes $2^n - 1$ and $2^m - 1$, make the size the period of each sequence as periodic infinite bit sequence. Adding them with XOR gives a new infinite bit sequence with the product of both periods as period (since they are coprime). Take one period of this sequence as the resulting PRBS $x$. This can be used as circulant matrix $K$, but on a permuted $v$: $v_i$ must then be the output of the ($i$ mod $2^n - 1$)th sampler on timeframe $i$ mod $2^m - 1$.

You can either reorder $v$ for JPL codes, or use instead the approach from my comments and find the matrix $M=(S_{ij} + T_{kl})_{nm}$ (mod 2) with $i=n, j=m, k=n, l=m$ modulo the other sequence length. It might be that it depends on the context which one is better. The autocorrelation of $K$ is the same as that of $M$ since it's merely permuted. Edit: no that does not follow. But the autocorrelation of the samplers is that of the maximal length sequence, and the autocorrelation over the timeframes the other sequence.

I'm not sure what to do if you can't exactly control the amount of timeframes, but I think it's fine to add zeroes at the end of $v$ to get the right dimension.